# IBM Worklight Studio Server not starting and not opening Worklight Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have recently installed Eclipse Juno 4.2 and IBM Worklight Studio 6.2.

I have created one demo project but its not running due to Following  reason

1. Worklight Server Not starting
2. Cant Open Worklight Console.

   Check Attached Screenshot For error

1.i have created one server
[image]

2.and i have start by right clicking on server.
got error

[image]

3.I cant find option "Run on IBM WORKLIGHT DEVELOPMENT SERVER" in Option Menu

[image]

4.When i try to open Worklight Console it  throw error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you absolutly need not "create a server". This is done for you automatically.
You only need to:

- Install Worklight Studio
- Click the Worklight icon in the menu bar and select to create a new project and application
- *Expend* the Worklight project from the Project Explorer view and *right-click on the application folder* (not the project folder like you've done)
- Now you **will** see the Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server option...

This is all covered in the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/).

Comment: i did but still not found this option check http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=72b0c32

Comment: Is this with the "server" you created? Please use a new workspace and try again based on my instructions.

Comment: means i need to create new WorkSpace trying

Comment: Happens sometimes... Open the servers view, select the server and click the play button to start the server

Comment: Did you change - in any way - the HTML file? Also make sure you are using **Eclipse 4.2.2 for Java EE** or **Eclipse 4.3.2 for Java EE** or **Eclipse 4.4 for Java EE**, with emphasis on the **Java EE**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58953/discussion-between-ando-masahashi-and-idan-adar).

Comment: Starting build process: application 'Hello', all environments 
[2014-08-08 16:42:59]             Application 'Hello' with all environments build finished.
[2014-08-08 16:42:59]             Deploying application 'Hello' with all environments to Worklight Server... 
[2014-08-08 16:43:16]             Failed to deploy application 'Hello' to Worklight Server: Connection to http://192.***.**.1:10080 refused

Comment: kill your java process; make sure there are no other eclipse process, make sure your firewall is not blocking the port.

Comment: Try with oracle Java 1.6 installed.

Comment: CWWKZ0005E: The application Helloworld cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application WorklightConsole cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application _analytics cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.